# Pandas DataFrame .replace() only replacing substring at beginning of string

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I want to replace all instances of a substring throughout a dataframe. If I do one substring at a time, it works:

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame([{'X':'abc','Y':'def','Z':'ghi'},
                {'X':'abc2','Y':'def2','Z':'ghi2'}],index = [0,1])
In: tdf
Out: 
      X     Y     Z
0   abc   def   ghi
1  abc2  def2  ghi2

In: tdf.replace('e','2',regex=True)
Out: 
      X     Y     Z
0   abc   d2f   ghi
1  abc2  d2f2  ghi2
```

But if I use two matched lists (I have a lot of substrings to replace), I only seem to be able to replace substrings at the beginning of strings:

```
In:tdf.replace(['e','a'],['1','2'],regex=True)
Out: 
      X     Y     Z
0   2bc   def   ghi
1  2bc2  def2  ghi2
```

How can I replace all the substrings with their respective values everywhere in one line?

pandas version '0.24.1'

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `dict`:

```
tdf=tdf.replace(dict(zip(['e','a'],['1','2'])),regex=True)
      X     Y     Z
0   2bc   d1f   ghi
1  2bc2  d1f2  ghi2
```

Comment: Yeah I had tried that as well. It still doesn't work for me:
tdf.replace(dict(zip(['e','a'],['1','2'])),regex=True)
Out: 
      X     Y     Z
0   2bc   def   ghi
1  2bc2  def2  ghi2
Is this a version issue?